# Error when attempting to use the mapply function in R Shiny Application

Tags: r, shiny, mapply

In the shiny app that I'm creating I am attempting to add two lists together using the mapply function, however the program is displaying the following error whenever I attempt to run it.

```
ERROR:  object 'SIMPLIFY' not found
```

Here is the code in question

```
addedUp <-  mapply("+", a, b, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Simplify is clearly there with no typographical errors so I am totally at a loss for what may be causing this issue. I've tried googling the problem and have not found anything mentioning this specific error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Hmisc/versions/4.0-3/topics/mApply), the simplify argument is not capitalized. (Although it is capitalized when I look at help(mapply) in R. Maybe this works:

```
addedUp <-  mapply("+", a, b, simplify=FALSE)
```

Alternatively, you can try:

```
Map('+',a,b)
```

Hope this helps.